# set icon size of a maker icon in a GMapPanel, ExtJS

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs

is there a way to set the size of a marker icon on a GMapPanel in extjs?  Im trying to display a map with thumbnail images on the map but the images are loading full size and i want it to display small thumbnails instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to setup a resizing function to resize the image by adding a default icon size to the image url.

```
/content/image.png?height=50&width=50
```

then i took the image and created a thumbnail size version and used the thumbnail image as the marker.